# Diagrams characterizing ring characteristic, and in particular field characteristic 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory, positive-characteristic

1. For a given prime $p$, what is the diagram for saying (e.g. in some category where morphisms are field homomorphisms) that a field has characteristic $p$?
2. Is there a diagram, or the shape of what such a diagram would look like, for $F_{un}$, the [field of characteristic 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)? More directly, is $F_{un}$ characterized by a diagram?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Moreover, the field with one element is not a field (and it may not be at all, for all we know...)

Comment: 1. If $K$ is a field with characteristic $p$, then $\mathcal i:\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\to K$ given by $\mathcal i(\overline n)=n\cdot1_K$ is a such diagram. It is clear that this approach is completely useless to solve your second question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I'm asking for a way of looking at the field of characteristic 1 in terms of morphisms. But I guess that's silly, because it doesn't have morphisms to or from anything else?

Comment: This is silly because you don't define $F_{\mathrm{un}}$. There is no consensus about what is the field with one element. It is a name for a vague notion of what _should be_ the base field of some degenerate geometries.

Comment: The current question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The notion of $F_{un}$ is not vague. Many frameworks have been built up (see the paper "Mapping F1-land" for example) in which precise and rigorous definitions of $F_{un}$ are given. Although Mariano is right that $F_{un}$ is not a field, it is a "generalized" field and in each proposed framework $F_{un}$ shares properties which fields in the usual sense have; for example, every module over $F_{un}$ should be free.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ahh, nice to see a reasonable defense of $\mathbb{F}_1$.  Poorly understood yes, inadequately defined as an analytic object yes, but vaguely defined algebraically, no.  The "field of one element" has a fairly standard and stable definition—unfortunately, the popular expectation that it would somehow immediately prove the Riemann Hypothesis has given it some lukewarm press.